# error: array subscript has type 'char' in a function (C)

Tags: c

I wrote the following function in C:

```
void count(int arr[N]) {
    char current;
    while(scanf(" %c", &current) > 0 && (current != '#'))
    {
        if(current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') {
            current += 32;
        } else if(current < 'a' || current > 'z') {
            continue;
        }
        current -= 97;
        arr[current]++;
    }
}
```

Although I get a warning when compiling: `error: array subscript has type 'char'`. Cant I user `current` as `int` value?

Comment: Just make it `arr[current - 97]++;` ...

Comment: Your code subtracts `97` (possibly `'a'`) when `isupper(current)` is true (please look up `isupper()` etc). `32` is added and then `97` subtracted. So you then use a negative index in `arr[current]++;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. what if I want to use `arr[current]` without using math in the `[]`

Comment: You could try making it `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` type can be signed or unsigned depending on the compiler configuration. The warning tells you that is `current` happens to be negative, the code would have undefined behavior as you would probably access and attempt to modify a byte outside the array boundaries. Given your code and assuming the target system uses ASCII, it is not going to happen.

You can prevent the warning by computing the offset from `'a'` directly as an `int` expression instead of updating the `char` variable.

Here is a modified version, that still assumes ASCII but uses more explicit character values:

```
void count(int arr[N]) {
    char current;
    while (scanf(" %c", &current) > 0 && current != '#') {
        if (current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') {
            arr[current - 'A']++;
        } else if (current >= 'a' && current <= 'z') {
            arr[current - 'a']++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int` can be negative too, but it won't warn.

Comment: @EugeneSh.`int` won't change signedness from platform to platform, which is apparently what the warning is worried about.

Comment: Given the tests and assuming ASCII, both `current - 'A'` and `current 
 - 'a'` are in the range `0..25`. The `char` variable is promoted to `int` before the subtraction and the result has type `int` which does not produce a warning.